# Small aircraft performance enhancements due to winglets?

Tags: winglets

I'm seeing some Beechcraft Barons with winglets.  Do these improve performance and, if so, by how much?

Comment: welcome to aviation.se. Did you have a look at our old questions on the subject(https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2111/1467 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8556/1467) ? is there something still not clear that you would like explained?